# How to get parent of recursive array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, recursion, parent-child

I have an array like this:

```
$navArray = array(
    array(
        'id'=>1,
        'text'=>'1A',
        'href'=>'1a',
        'childs'=>array(
            array(
                'id'=>2,
                'text'=>'1B',
                'href'=>'1b',
                'childs'=>array(
                    array(
                        'id'=>4,
                        'text'=>'4D',
                        'href'=>'4d',
                        'childs'=>array()
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'=>5,
                        'text'=>'5E',
                        'href'=>'5e',
                        'childs'=>array(
                            array(
                                'id'=>6,
                                'text'=>'6F',
                                'href'=>'6f',
                                'childs'=>array()
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id'=>7,
                                'text'=>'7G',
                                'href'=>'7g',
                                'childs'=>array()
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
                )
            ),
            array(
                'id'=>3,
                'text'=>'3C',
                'href'=>'3c',
                'childs'=>array(
                    array(
                        'id'=>8,
                        'text'=>'8H',
                        'href'=>'8h',
                        'childs'=>array()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I can traverse the multidimensional array and return the 'key' => 'value' pairs:

```
displayRecs($navArray);

function displayRecs($navArray) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($navArray));
    foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
        echo ($key . ' ' . $value . '<br>');
    }
}
```

The snapshot below visualize the the result.

[image]

I would like to get finally the following array:

```
$finalArray = array(
    array('id'=>1,'parent'=>0,'text'=>'1A','href'=>'1a'),
    array('id'=>2,'parent'=>1,'text'=>'2B','href'=>'2b'),
    array('id'=>3,'parent'=>1,'text'=>'3C','href'=>'3c'),
    array('id'=>4,'parent'=>2,'text'=>'4D','href'=>'4d'),
    array('id'=>5,'parent'=>2,'text'=>'5E','href'=>'5e'),
    array('id'=>6,'parent'=>5,'text'=>'6F','href'=>'6f'),
    array('id'=>7,'parent'=>5,'text'=>'7G','href'=>'7g'),
    array('id'=>8,'parent'=>3,'text'=>'8H','href'=>'8h'),
);
```

How to get the 'id' for the parent array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
function displayRec($a, $parent = "0") {
    echo "id: {$a['id']} parent: {$parent} text: {$a['text']} href: {$a['href']}";
    echo "\n";
    if (!empty($a['childs'])) {
        foreach($a['childs'] as $child) {
            displayRec($child, $a['id']);
        }
        
    }
}

foreach($navArray as $a) {
    displayRec($a);
}
```

I just tested it with your original array, it displays:

> id: 1 parent: 0 text: 1A href: 1a
>
> id: 2 parent: 1 text: 1B href: 1b
>
> id: 4 parent: 2 text: 4D href: 4d
>
> id: 5 parent: 2 text: 5E href: 5e
>
> id: 6 parent: 5 text: 6F href: 6f
>
> id: 7 parent: 5 text: 7G href: 7g
>
> id: 3 parent: 1 text: 3C href: 3c
>
> id: 8 parent: 3 text: 8H href: 8h

I hope it will help! My (recursive) function *displays* the result, you can easily adapt it to get this as an array.

Answer (score 2):

You should do a manual solution.

```
function getArray($array, $parent = 0) { 
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $member) {
        $result[] = array_intersect_key($member, [ "id" => "", "text" => "", "href" => "" ])+["parent"=>$parent];
        $result = array_merge($result, getArray((isset($member["childs"])?$member["childs"]:[]), $member["id"]));
    }
    return $result;
};

print_r(getArray($navArray));
```

Example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eff98096efb54db9e37da0777ab243155bfab170

Comment: I checked in the sandbox, awesome solution and works perfect.

Comment: @bisn apokryfox is a solid poster on SO, you can trust his work.